# jQuery set cookie in column table show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

How to set cookie in column table hide/show function? So if user click hide then it will remember the browser that it still hide by cookie function when we refresh the page.

Function hide

```
function hideCol(columnClass){
      $('table .'+columnClass).each(function(index) {
        $(this).hide();
      });

      $('ul#hiddenCols').append('<li id="'+columnClass+'"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="showCol(\''+columnClass+'\');">Show '+columnClass+'</a></li>');
    }
```

Function show

```
function showCol(columnClass){
      $('table .'+columnClass).each(function(index) {
        $(this).show();
      });

      $('li#'+columnClass).remove();
    }
```

Please help to advice.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery cookie
set cookie show/hide when process function

```
function hideCol(columnClass){
  $('table .'+columnClass).each(function(index) {
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $('ul#hiddenCols').append('<li id="'+columnClass+'"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="showCol(\''+columnClass+'\');">Show '+columnClass+'</a></li>');
 $.cookie("remember_state","hide"); //add it
}

function showCol(columnClass){
  $('table .'+columnClass).each(function(index) {
    $(this).show();
  });

  $('li#'+columnClass).remove();
     $.cookie("remember_state","show"); //add it
}
```

Add function when document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($.cookie("remember_state")=="hide"){
    //hide function
}else{
//show function
}
});
```

Comment: @charlietfl use $.cookie("remember_state"+columnClass,"show/hide");

Comment: @HDT it's not me you need to explain it to, I know how to make it work. It's your solution that doesn't handle what OP needs